# 500 Server Error on Classic ASP - Cannot get more details

Tags: iis, logging, asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

Windows 2008 R2 Standard x64, with IIS 7.5

When trying to load any ASP page (in IE right on the server), I instantly receive a "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error". I have un-ticked "show friendly error messages" in IE.

IIS Logs show:

> "ASP_0147|500_Server_Error".

Event Viewer->Application gives me:

> Error: ASP will not serve requests because it could not perform the first request initialization..

And finally, the usually helpful Failed Request Tracing gives me 2 entries:

```
ASP_LOG_ERROR (Labeled as ERROR)
LineNumber: 
ErorrCode: ASP 0147
Description: 500 Server Error

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS (Labeled as WARNING)
ModuleName: IsapiModule
Notification: 128
HttpStatus: 500
HttpReason: Server Error
HttpSubStatus: 0
ErrorCode: 0
ConfigExceptionInfo:
Notification: EXECUTE REQUEST HANDLER
ErrorCode: The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

I have double-checked all permissions and accounts. I have switched the app pool pipeline mode back and forth. And of course, I removed the IIS role from the server, and reinstalled that and the ASP Role Service about 5 times. I also have the Error Pages setting at the site level to show "Detailed Errors". I get the same errors for every ASP page, including a test one that is nothing but a response.write.

The real kicker is that I had this working when I came in this morning. I don't know if I clicked something in IIS by mistake or what. I have scoured the web for the past 8 hours. Experts -- what happened?

Comment: Did you get the same error trace when using the classic pipeline?

Comment: Yes, the same error trace happens with classic as integrated.

Comment: I re-imaged the server, and repeated my steps. Everything worked great  until I deleted the default web site. Now I am back to getting the same 500 errors. What could have messed up by deleting the Default Web Site (which had been stopped all along anyway?)

Comment: Did you guys figure this one out further?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was never resolved. I ended up rebuilding the server and disabling the default web site instead of deleting. (I had seen some vague references to IIS having problems if the default website was deleted at a certain point during creating new sites. This may have been part of my problem.)

Answer (score 2):

A few steps that you may try:

1. Ensure that there is no global.asa file of 0 bytes.
2. Try creating a new web site only for test and see if that is also not working. Then put a text file and try browsing it. If a text file comes up good, it would mean your IIS is okay. Now, try ASP file with `<%=Now%>` and see if you get the latest time. If this doesn't work, then it is related with permissions. In that case, use Process Monitor to find out any Access Denied and fix it. Check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/01/18/using-filemon-regmon-to-solve-quot-access-denied-quot-issues.aspx).

The download links have changed: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Note: in case you don't see any access denied, try this

1. Start ProcMon
2. IISRESET
3. Browse .asp page again and check for Access Denied.

Comment: Great suggestion! In Process Monitor, there is a BUFFER OVERFLOW every time an ASP page is hit. I don't know how that can happen as the asp pages are very simple, including a test page that shows <%=NOW%> as suggested. .NET pages work fine, as does everything else I tried such as graphics and txt files.

Comment: Start Procmon... IISReset... Browse any .asp page. Save the log file and send it across to rahulso@microsoft.com. I will see if there is anything fishy. Once done with this exercise, also send me trace files.